# Migrating standalone application to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I do have a standalone application that is started through a main method, which is based on the Spring Framework and uses JavaFX for the user interface.

At the moment there is one main class, which parses the command line arguments and depending on the outcome sets up the Spring configuration. There are three distinctive configurations:

- Server (no user interface or server user interface)
- Client (only user interface)
- Standalone (server and client run in the same application

With the current approach I can decide on the Spring configuration, however with Spring Boot the application basically becomes the top level configuration.

This lead me to the conclusion, that I will need three distinctive Spring Boot applications. As the whole project is set up with Maven the main class is in one module that depends on all others. I also have the Maven build set up to create an executable jar, as well as an executable application.

If I have three different Spring Boot applications, would that mean that I need to put them in different modules?

Based on this build configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ch.sahits.game.OpenPatrician</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>unix</id>
        <activation>
            <os><family>unix</family></os>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>ch.sahits.game.OpenPatrician</mainClass>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <bundler>linux.app</bundler>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>        </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os><family>windows</family></os>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>ch.sahits.game.OpenPatrician</mainClass>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>build-installer</id>
        <properties>
            <native.output.dir>${project.build.directory}/jfx/native/${project.build.finalName}</native.output.dir>
            <native.output.dir.app>${native.output.dir}/app</native.output.dir.app>
            <native.app.jar>${native.output.dir.app}/${project.build.finalName}-jfx.jar</native.app.jar>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.sahits.game</groupId>
                <artifactId>OpenPatricianDisplay</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>

            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>native</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create zip archive</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>

                                    <echo>Creating self-contained zip native</echo>
                                    <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/OpenPatrician-${project.version}-[OS]64.zip" basedir="${native.output.dir}" />

                                    <echo>Creating self-contained executable jar</echo>
                                    <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/OpenPatrician-${project.version}.zip" basedir="${native.output.dir.app}" />

                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Should I change to the Spring Boot way to create an executable Jar file, or would this approach still work?

Comment: why would you change if it works...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 as a learning experience and I expect this to be long running, so keeping up with changes are part of the challenge of the project.

Comment: sounds good, check out this: https://springboot-javafx-support.readthedocs.io/en/latest/